# Sync master volume with application volume

Tags: macos, audio, software-recommendation, sound-volume

Is there a way to sync master volume with app volume on the mac?

e.g. I have Spotify app playing on my mac and I would like to trigger master volume up and volume down from the Spotify app as well I would like to trigger Spotify app volume from the master volume controls.

The issue I want to solve is that I'm using mac as sound system controller with Spotify connect feature which allows to control Spotify volume on mac from another device, but I also have a volume controller connected to the mac which controls mac volume. Because of this setup mac and Spotify volume is always out of sync..

EDIT:
Thought about this more and looks like the easier solution would be to remap master volume controls to trigger Spotify app instead of master volume. Looks like it's possible on Windows but I wasn't able to find anything for macOS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPkYoXmGMRs

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: Wouldn’t this be up to the app developer to not implement volume separately and depend on external volume controls? Apps have to go to trouble to implement their own settings, so this seems like - how do I ask Spotify to add a feature to just follow the system? Perhaps I’m not understanding your end goal

Comment: @bmike Yeah, that is exactly what I want, but I had hopes that there is a work around to this since it takes ages for Spotify to implement a feature.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/beardedspice/beardedspice -- they do a lot with media keys.